# Generate a string based on boolean object props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object like

```
{
  cash: true, 
  credit: false, 
  debit: true
}
```

need to generate a string in this case  "Cash, Debit"

Comment: You should make your question more explanatory, I guess you want to return the keys only if the value is true?

Comment: hi John Welcome to S/O take a look over here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: your question is not clear at all.  check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, using `Object.keys` you can do a `filter()`:

```js
var Obj = {
  cash: true, 
  credit: false, 
  debit: true
};

console.log(
  Object.keys(Obj)
    .filter(function (key) {
      return Obj[key];
    })
);
```

If you want to add some formatting like make it completely string with the first letter capitalised, you can use `map()` and `join()` function:

```js
var Obj = {
  cash: true, 
  credit: false, 
  debit: true
};

console.log(
  Object.keys(Obj)
    .filter(function (key) {
      return Obj[key];
    })
    .map(function (string) {
      return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    })
    .join(", ")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.entries`, filter out the `false`, then map to the first element in each entry (uppercasing the first letter), and join the result

```js
const result = Object.entries({cash: true, credit: false, debit: true})
                     .filter(([_,v]) => v)
                     .map((v) => v[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v[0].slice(1))
                     .join(', ')

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's a bit advanced using `Object.entries()`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want the list of keys with value equals to true.

E.g

```
let obj = {
  cash: true, 
  credit: false, 
  debit: true
}

let arr = [];

for(let prop in obj) {
  if(obj(prop) == true) arr.push(prop)
}

console.log(arr) //cash,debit
```

Comment: You can just simply use a filter to do this without creating a separate array.

Comment: He wants an array of the keys.

Comment: Still it's possible without declaring an extra array, sorry that's what I meant.

Comment: Ofcourse, but that will mutate the original object

Comment: No no, it won't.  `.map()` creates a new array.

Answer (score 0):

This is just another variation of the other answers, with included string manipulation for proper grammatical display, tho more verbose than pushing in an array and using `.join(', ')`. It is probably not the solution I would employ in the real world, but hopefully does illustrate possibly ways to sort and handle data.

```
let obj = {
  cash: true, 
  credit: false, 
  debit: true
},

let finalString = '';
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.forEach((key, index) => {
    if (obj[key]) {
      const keyString = `${key.capitalize()}';
      const comma = index !== keys.length -1 ? ', ' : '';
      finalString += (keyString + comma);
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

use this function :

```
function make_string(x){
   var string = ""
   Object.keys(x).filter(function (key) {
      string += x[key] ? `${key},` : '';
   })
   return string.slice(0, -1)
}
```

for example :

```
var payments = {
  cash: true, 
  credit: false, 
  debit: true
}
console.log(make_string(payments))
```

---

### --------------- the code snippet is here --------------

```js
var payment = {
  cash: true, 
  credit: false, 
  debit: true
}
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = make_string(payment)


//---- the function to make string from object ----//
function make_string(x){
    var string = ""
    Object.keys(x).filter(function (key) {
        string += x[key] ? `${key},` : '';
    })
    return string.slice(0, -1)
}
```

```html
<div id="abc"></div>
```